# Payment made to invalid IBAN missing last 2 digits, Payment is still in reservation. Where is has the money gone? Payment was from Belgium to UK

Tags: international-transfer, iban

Payment from Belgium bank to UK.

Missed last 2 digits from IBAN in receiving UK account.

Will the payment get bounced?

Money is shown as being reserved?

Comment: I'm not too familiar, but remember that money doesn't just disappear, and there are humans in the process. If you are worried, you can call your bank and find out what is happening. If you are not worried, you can wait and see. *Usually,* deleting digits from an account number does not create a valid account number, so they will see the account number is invalid. Sometimes the last few digits are a "sub-account" and the money will go to that person's main account by default. I don't know the specifics of your situation, these are just some general principles.

Comment: "money doesn't just disappear" unfortunately: it's quite common that money "totally disappears" when sent to the wrong / meaningless account.  It's a thing.  IBANs are less of a problem than the US system, but it happens for sure.  (The sentences beginning "Usually" and "Sometimes" are not correct for IBANs, unfortunately.)

Answer (score 1):

Every destination country has its fixed IBAN length. If the IBAN has the wrong length, the payment won't go through and will eventually be reversed.

Even if the IBAN length won't be checked, it will in most cases disturb the checksum, and the number is invalid as described before.

The chance that the modification doesn't alter the checksum (position 3 and 4) is 1:97, so in very few cases the payment could go through to a wrong account number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to phone your Belgian bank ***immediately***.

IBANs are a mess, for example if you leave off the two digits of the bank part up front it can still be kind of valid at the other end. It's pathetic that they allowed you to enter an invalid IBAN but it's a common enough problem.

1. In answer to your question it ***will not*** unfortunately get bounced back to you, unless you intervene in the most aggressive way possible
2. It's *unlikely* you will ultimately "totally lose" you money, but *it's not unknown and can happen*. You have to get on to the bank this morning, aggressively
3. It's gonna take a surprisingly long time to resolve, be aware if you're doing something urgent.